# Creating generic method names in generic class?

Tags: java, generics

Currently, I have something like this:-

```
public class MyHolder<T> {
    private T   value;

    public MyHolder(T t) {
        this.value = t;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setValue(T t) {
        this.first = t;
    }
}
```

With this, I can use it like this:-

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
MyHolder<MyBean> obj = new MyHolder<MyBean>(bean);
obj.getValue(); // returns bean
```

Instead of calling the getter/setter to be `getValue()` and `setValue(..)`, is it possible to "generify" that too?

Essentially, it would be nice to have it `getMyBean()` and `setMyBean(..)`, depending on the type passed in. Granted this is a very simple example, however if I create a generic holder class that takes N generic properties, then it would be nice to call it something meaningful instead of `getValue1()` or `getValue2()`, and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't create a generic holder class that takes N generic properties. Make an actual class with a useful name and useful field names.

Comment: I'm quite sure it couldn't be used the way you'd like, even if it was possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no such feature in Java. I can't even imagine how it would look syntactically... `void set<T>();`? And how would the getter / setter for for instance `MyHolder<? extends Number>` look?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible unless you use some kind of source code generator to have the `MyHolder` class generated based on your input.

But on the other hand, even if you had this possibility, how it would be different from using a `Map<String, T>`? So the invocation would read:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
MyHolder<MyBean> obj = new MyHolder<MyBean>(bean);
obj.get('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible. Java generics are based on type erasure, i.e. it's mostly syntactic sugar provided by the compiler. That means each generic class is actually implemented by a "raw type" where are type parameters are `Object` and which already contains all the methods. So it's fundamentally not possible to have different methods depending on type parameters.

Comment: I wouldn't say erasures have to do with it. If there was a syntax for it, the compiler could derive such method names. It's simply just not supported.

Comment: I don't think erasure precludes this since it could be an entirely compile-time thing that's reduced to the original method name for runtime purposes. Not to say that there aren't a ton of other problems with the idea.

Comment: Erasures has a bit to do with it - you'd have a method `getMyBean` in the source code and what in compiled code? With `getValue` it wouldn't compile. So you'd have to put `getMyBean` there, which is reified and not erasure.

Comment: In the compiled code, you would obviously have a method called `getMyBean`.