# effect or animation in UItableVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c

when I click on the tableView it displays something like this to show details

How can I do this?:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is an implementation similar to accordion. Here are some sample reference from where you can start

[How to implement an accordion view for an iPhone SDK app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944428/how-to-implement-an-accordion-view-for-an-iphone-sdk-app)

[Accordion table cell - How to dynamically expand/contract uitableviewcell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066167/accordion-table-cell-how-to-dynamically-expand-contract-uitableviewcell)

[Accordion sample tutorial](http://www.deepinthecouch.com/iphone-sdk/accordion-uitableviews-programming-backwards)

[Accordion sample tutorial 2](http://www.deepinthecouch.com/iphone-sdk/accordion-uitableviews)

Comment: the site for the Accordion sample tutorials appears to be down. Is this mirrored anywhere that you know of?