# UI split view app for ipad 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

List item inside a item in split view in ipad
I am making an ipad app i want that if i have a three items in table view 
A B C and inside A i have abc like this so how may i do this and how may go to detail page after doing this thanks in ipad app

Comment: :O ???? What was your question again?

Comment: My question is that i want collapsable table view Like it Shows Fruits ,Vegetable like that and when i click fruit it show all the names of fruits like in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5633346/591951).

[Tutorial 1: Expanding/Collapsing TableView Sections](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)

[Example 1: UIExpandableTableView for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uiexpandabletableview) 
[Exapmle 2: Accordion for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/accordion) 
[Example 3: VPPDropDown for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/vppdropdown)

Comment: I have seen this first and also i am getting little bit of first only i just want that i have three header fruits veg drinks and inside them can u hep me out

Comment: The example mentioned above provides a list of say N-items and when you click on one of the items, it expands and show the N-subCatagoryItems. I believe your requirement is also something similar . please try downloading the examples i mentioned above.

Comment: i have downloaded but not getting same i dont want accessory extra i only want collapse only

Comment: can you paste simple code for just two items heades and inside them one one item plz if you can

Comment: Nobody will provide you the exact thing you want, In the above examples you will find the code to implement your requirement.There is no substitute for hard work.

Comment: Mark my answer as correct if it was helpful for you in some way

Answer (score 0):

Use below link..

http://redartisan.com/2010/6/14/uisplitviewcontroller-views

http://redartisan.com/2010/6/14/uisplitviewcontroller-views

thanks

Comment: no i want collapsable table view first it  show only three cat Animal,Fruits,Veg and when i press any it shows table view inside that cat in collapsable formate

Comment: I have done as your but i want like this http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40351-collapse-tableview-sections.html

Comment: but i am not getting in this link easily

Comment: this is not a split View.. your question is wrong...this is Node and subnode content in the Tableview..you can use that code and there write any body .. try that code success of your link..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview like this i want as he is saying

Comment: NOW WHAT YOU WANT..THERE IS SAMPLE CODE AVAILABLE..OF YOUR LINK

Comment: No i m not aggressive i want like to help you so please let me explain in details. so may be i help you..

Comment: details are like this dear that when you open ipad app which is split view in table view it should display only three cells or header what ever you understand and on click on any it expands and shows the list of related

Comment: can u give me ur email address or skype so that i may send u screen which is look a like which i want

Comment: come on stackoverflow iphone /ipad  chat and ping me there

Comment: i have added  on gmail via ur email for chat

Comment: hi..come on skype..let me discuss