# UITableView with open & closed sections

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView with several sections.
I would like click on a section to "close/open" its content, in order to show/hide the rows under it. So that, I can keep some sections open (with its rows visible) and others close, with the next section immediately below the previous section header.

How can I implement it? Do I need to subclass the UITableView and add a gesture recognizer and somehow add an animation to the rows? But I'm not sure this is easy...

thanks

Comment: This is the best site for any [custom Controller.](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UItableView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`reloadSections:withRowAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW36) to trigger the change;
2. Provide the updated number of rows in [UITableViewDataSource delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW8)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment for the question as I don't have enough reputation. 
As per my understanding, you want to achieve accordion functionality for your table view.
 For this, please check this:-
 [effect or animation in UItableVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633287/effect-or-animation-in-uitableview) and 
 [How to implement an accordion view for an iPhone SDK app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944428/how-to-implement-an-accordion-view-for-an-iphone-sdk-app)

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass sectionHeaderView and define delegate methods like this.

```
@protocol SectionHeaderViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)section;
-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)section;

@end
```

And then in tableViewCOntroller.h

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <SectionHeaderViewDelegate>
```

And in tableViewCOntroller.m

```
-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)sectionOpened 
{

    SectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:sectionOpened];

    sectionInfo.open = YES;

    /*
     Create an array containing the index paths of the rows to insert: These correspond to the rows for each quotation in the current section.
     */
    NSInteger countOfRowsToInsert = [sectionInfo.play.quotations count];
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToInsert; i++) {
        [indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionOpened]];
    }

    /*
     Create an array containing the index paths of the rows to delete: These correspond to the rows for each quotation in the previously-open section, if there was one.
     */
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSInteger previousOpenSectionIndex = self.openSectionIndex;
    if (previousOpenSectionIndex != NSNotFound) {

        SectionInfo *previousOpenSection = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:previousOpenSectionIndex];
        previousOpenSection.open = NO;
        [previousOpenSection.headerView toggleOpenWithUserAction:NO];
        NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [previousOpenSection.play.quotations count];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:previousOpenSectionIndex]];
        }
    }

    // Style the animation so that there's a smooth flow in either direction.
    UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation;
    UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation;
    if (previousOpenSectionIndex == NSNotFound || sectionOpened < previousOpenSectionIndex) {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    }
    else {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
    }

    // Apply the updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    self.openSectionIndex = sectionOpened;

}


-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)sectionClosed 
{

    /*
     Create an array of the index paths of the rows in the section that was closed, then delete those rows from the table view.
     */
    SectionInfo *sectionInfo = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:sectionClosed];

    sectionInfo.open = NO;
    NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionClosed];

    if (countOfRowsToDelete > 0) 
    {
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionClosed]];
        }
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    self.openSectionIndex = NSNotFound;
    if ([selectedIndexes count]>0) 
    {
        for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexes)
        {
            if(sectionClosed == indexPath.section)
            {
                [sectionInfo.headerView changeOnHighlighted:YES];
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                [sectionInfo.headerView changeOnHighlighted:NO];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        {
                [sectionInfo.headerView changeOnHighlighted:NO];

        }

}
```

And for further details you can refer this [sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) from iOS dev lib..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution by which you can even create a custom expanded/ collapse view. 
here are simple step
1) create a custom view add button over it.
[image]
///
join all outlet and create on BOOL variable in view class

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *BtnAction;
@property(assign, nonatomic)BOOL isOpen;
```

// Create a header where tableview is added and you want it.
here is a simple logic to added as much as you need . I have added which are in headertitle array I wanted it to be dynamic .

```
NSMutableArray * headerTitle = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Your Order", @"Delivery Address", @"Pay By", nil];
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index<headerTitle.count; index++) {
    VGOrderHeader* HeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VGOrderHeader" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    HeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 40);
    HeaderView.BtnAction.tag = index;
    if (index == 0) {
        HeaderView.isOpen = YES;
        HeaderView.lblPlus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"open"];

    }
    [HeaderView.BtnAction addTarget:self action:@selector(selectSectionToOpen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerArray addObject:HeaderView];
}
```

/// Here is header click action.

```
-(void)selectSectionToOpen:(UIButton *)sender{
      for (NSUInteger Increment=0; Increment<headerArray.count; Increment++) {
        if (sender.tag == Increment) {
            DCOrderHeader* HeaderView= headerArray[Increment];
                HeaderView.isOpen = !HeaderView.isOpen;

         }
     }
    // little animation 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [UIView transitionWithView:self.tableView
                      duration:0.55f
                              options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^(void) {
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    } completion:NULL];
});

}
```

/// Finally Assign view in header method of table view and provide a height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [headerArray objectAtIndex:section];

}
```

// Final Touch

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return headerArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    DCOrderHeader* HeaderView = headerArray[section];
        if (HeaderView.isOpen == YES) {
              return self.someArray.count;
        }else{
              return 0;
            }
}
```