# Double accordeon in UItableView

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to develop some behavior in an iPhone app. My application is a Book. in the book i have Chapters and pages, the user can take notes in pages ( Highlight a text, bookmark a page,...), all this object are "UserInput". in one View of my application, i would like to implement a `UItableView` to represent all the UserInputs of the user ( notes, highlights,...), i would like to have a UITableView with : a rows which represent the chapters witch contain at least one userInput, when clicking the "Chapter row" the tableview should show to me all the "page rows" witch contain al least one "userInput" and finally when clicking a "row page" it shows to me all the userInput for the page. I would like to implement a double accordion in UItableView.

How i can do this please ? any suggestion ? thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

[How to implement an accordion view for an iPhone SDK app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944428/how-to-implement-an-accordion-view-for-an-iphone-sdk-app)

It might help though if you elaborate with a sketch that explained things a bit more clearly.